# How to achieve glow element using CSS in plain div like described below?

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

I am trying to convert PSD into HTML using CSS.

I have a plain rectangle like this :

[image: Plain Backgriund]

Now a oval shape glow element : ( As in PSD )

[image: Image Glow]

Because of this if you look at only rectangle , With a glow at top it looks like below :

[image: final]

How to achieve the same ? Any lead is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using Radial Gradients:**

You can sort of achieve that by placing a `radial-gradient` image on top of your rectangle with the solid color. The positioning and size of the gradient may need to be modified to suit your needs.

The `radial-gradient` that I had used is very similar to the one in your PSD image. That is is starts from a bluish color and then gradually moves to transparent. This gradient is then positioned such that its center point is at 75% width of the parent and a distance that is 25% of the parent's height above it.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(17, 45, 67);
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at 75% -25%, rgb(14, 102, 150) 0%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

The **main thing to worry** with using `radial-gradient` is the [relatively poor browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).

---

**Using Box Shadow:**

Below is a slightly different approach using a pseudo-element and `box-shadow`. The `box-shadow` has a very high spread radius which produces a glow like effect.

This has better browser support than `radial-gradient` (even as low as IE8) but `box-shadow` cannot take values in percentage and hence this solution wouldn't be very useful for dynamic sized containers.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: rgb(17, 45, 67);
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 150px;
  top: -250px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(14, 102, 150);
  box-shadow: 25px 25px 150px 250px rgba(14, 102, 150, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Is there any solution to get rid of sprinkles ( circular arc at the end of ellipse ) ?

Comment: If I try to do box shadow for very high resolution they seems to be drawing boxes. Check here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOEYdZ

Comment: @Manish: Unfortunately, that is something almost unavoidable with radial gradients. For the box shadow version, I am not seeing any boxes in the CodePen, there is only an ellipse. [Here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/OyPZmE) is a fork of your pen. The `top` is negative of your `height` and `right` is half of `width` as per my calculation.

Comment: Okay I get it. But with boxes I see this : http://s28.postimg.org/l9j7w8lt9/image.png 
This is not desired result.

Comment: @Manish: I still couldn't repro the problem seen in your image but I have updated the second snippet in my answer with the glow on a large sized element. Have a look and let me know if it works.

Comment: This does not give boxes now :)  Thanks.

Comment: Nice to note that mate :) @Manish.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can see is to use a pseudo element and put a gradient background on it. I've made this quickly to show you but it does not reproduce exactly your image :

```css
.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #112D43;
}
.rectangle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #094567 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Comment: Nice, we had very similar thoughts at around the same time :) Extra pseudo-element is actually not required as background image stacking is now possible.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpgdJM  looks nice. Any idea , how to remove rings at borders